# How can i declear a function/method in one time but use this multiple query Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

This is my `users` table

```
1.id
2.name
3......
```

My `branches` table

```
1.id
2.branch_name
3....
```

`members` table

```
1.id
2.branch_id
3.user_id
4.member_name
5......
```

One Pivot table name `branch-users`

```
1.id
2.user_id
3.branch_id
```

permitted branch id of an user store in this `branch_user` pivot table, when this user entry any member he can only see his assign branch list in `<select></select>` field or if want to see the member list. he can only see his assign branch member list.I have implement this such query in Laravel controller

**My index method section**

```
public function index(){
   $my = Auth::user()->branches;// branches is a many to many relation method in user model
     foreach($my as $my){
      $myBranch[] = $my->id;
      }
   $member = Member::whereIn('branch_id',$myBranch)->get();
   return view('member.create',compact('member'))
}
```

**My create method section**

```
public function create(){
  // i have to check every where this section...from....... 
   $my = Auth::user()->branches;
     foreach($my as $my){
      $myBranch[] = $my->id;
      }
  //.......to here
   $branch = Branch::whereIn('id',$myBranch)->get();
   return view('member.create',compact('branch'))
}
```

My problem is that i want to use this **`::whereIn('branch_id',$myBranch)->....`** where condition to display branch list and branch member list, everywhere i have to declare and check user assign branch list that is not good in Laravel framework , i know there have thus opportunities where i can declare any function one time and possible to use that function/method/variable multiple time. i want to check, one time authenticated user assign branch id and use multiple time where i need. but unfortunately i don't understand how can i do that. If any body understand what i have tried  to  say ,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write yourself a local scope query.  You put part of the query logic on the model, then you can call it anywhere you are trying to query that model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes